# HTML5 Canvas image gets blurred when repeatedly copyied on itself

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scroll

I have this problem with scrolling an tiled image, but only on mobile (android) browsers..

The image is "scrolled" by repainting it on itself, I had a version using an offscreen buffer but no difference. The coordinates are parsed to integers, as the touch events give floats. If this is not done, the effect is even worse. The canvas width/height attr are set equal to the css style width/height so the canvas is not scaled.

When i repeatedly scroll the canvas following touchmove events using the following code, the rendered image gets blurred more and more on mobile chrome browser - not so on desktop browsers.
See the image attached, the tiles in the middle are the affected, those at the borders get redrawn.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of scrolling a canvas?

```
worldRenderer.prototype.offset = function(dx,dy) {

    dx = parseInt(dx);
    dy = parseInt(dy)

    this.ctx.drawImage(this.canvas, dx, dy);

    var obounds = this.calcVisible();
    this.options.offsetx += dx;
    this.options.offsety += dy;
    var bounds = this.calcVisible();
    var x0 = bounds[0];
    var x1 = bounds[2];

    if (dx>0) {
        this.paintRect(this.ctx, [bounds[0],bounds[1],obounds[0],bounds[3]]);
        x0=obounds[0];
    } else if (dx<0) {
        this.paintRect(this.ctx, [obounds[2],bounds[1],bounds[2],bounds[3]]);
        x1=obounds[2];
    }
    if (dy>0) {
        this.paintRect(this.ctx, [x0,bounds[1],x1,obounds[1]] );
    } else if (dy<0) {
        this.paintRect(this.ctx, [x0,obounds[3],x1,bounds[3]]) ;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is probably because of anti-aliasing, the easiest solution is to `clearRect()` before redrawing. An other solution would be to set [`ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) to false (be careful it needs vendor prefixes though.) Also, when you say "The canvas width/height attr are set equal to the css style width/height" I am wondering, are you setting both CSS and HTML parameters? If so, try to remove CSS one completely.

Comment: Yes it was an antialiasing effect - but the image does not get resampled, it is the same size so this should not happen? 
I already set the flag when creating the context, but somehow this gets unset. This I consider a bug, but when I set ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled right before the drawImage the images do not get blurred.

Comment: I you change the width or height properties of the canvas, the whole context's properties are reset. To avoid any CSS aliasing, always avoid setting canvas size through CSS.

Comment: Ah thats it: setting the canvas size resetted the imageSmoothingEnabled! The css and canvas sizes where set by script to the same value at the same time, to esure there will be no antialiasing through css. But one question remains, why does the browser smooth the image if it is just blitted, not resized?